# Can't run project in eclipse after adding to repo. Not a java project

Tags: eclipse, github, eclipse-plugin, egit, jgit

I set up my github account and egit. It works really well. I have learned the staging, committing, push/pulling ... pretty much.

Unfortunately (Juno) Eclipse is not recognizing FoobarProstate as a Java project. It says FoobarProstate is simply a project. When I click the green run arrow I get the error message

> The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches.

I created the project in Eclipse, imported it with the wizard using **File > Import > Git > Projects from Git.** That might be my mistake.

This is what I see in the Eclipse Package Explorer.

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse package explorer]

What I've tried:

- **Right click on project name > Configure** gives me one option: **Convert to Maven Project**. I don't know what that is and I don't think I want that.
- **Green run dropdown arrow > Run As** gives me *(none applicable)*.
- I can't figure out the online instructions to change to a project to a java project.

In the answers I've found online, it says to change the run configurations (**Green run dropdown arrow > Run Configurations...**). But the instructions are either not for Juno, or difficult to follow. I'm really confused.

Notes:

- In the github view of my repositories, it says "Java" next to this repo's name! The repo has the same name (FoobarProstate) as my Java project.
- My FoobarProstate files are stored in C:\Users\EmilyBB\git\FoobarProstate. This is not my Eclipse workspace (C:\Users\EmilyBB\workspace). Is that a problem?
- I just installed Android stuff (ADT etc.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is likely that somewhere along the way, the original .project and .classpath files were lost.  Together they indicate that the project is a Java Project and what its Java Build Path--including where your sources are within the project.  Not physically being under the workspace directory should not be an issue.

The .project file contents should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>YOUR project's name</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
**Right click on project name > Configure> Convert to Faceted Form>** Choose in the appeared window Java and click 'OK'